# Problems with delegate and strings

Tags: c#, string, delegates

I have a question about delegates, I were googling have several days and could not find anything usefull that could help-me solve a problem.

Well, I created a delegate and then declared it, but the script it will run will be writen in a string value.

For example, if the string value is:
"Console.WriteLine("Hello");
 Console.ReadKey();"
I want the delegate value to pass that to code and then read and execute that code.

Does someone know how could i do that?

```
namespace TestScript
{
    class Program
    {
        delegate void TestScript();
        static TestScript LastScript;

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string Directory = Environment.CurrentDirectory;
            string TestCode = "Console.WriteLine(\"Test\");\nConsole.ReadKey();";
            TestScript script; //?
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It has nothing to do with delegates. It's about compiling code while executing your own.

Comment: You will have to reflect the string and then execute it. There's no built in function to do this for you.

Comment: You can take a look at spring.net chapter 13

Comment: I think that's not what i'm looking for.

Comment: You may want to use this http://www.csscript.net

Comment: Thank you! I'm kind of disappointed that Microsoft didn't even thought about the possibility of using strings as delegate method body, but the CSScript seems to turn that into truth. Beside refferencing the dll of CSScript, i had also to refference the Mono.Csharp dll aswell, which also comes with the zip. Well, Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Mono comes with a C# compiler as a service (it works in both Mono and .Net) which can evaluate c# code at run-time, here is a simple example based on your question:

```
public delegate void TestScript();

class Program
{
    private static Evaluator _evaluator;

    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        _evaluator = new Evaluator(new CompilerContext(new CompilerSettings(), new ConsoleReportPrinter()));

        var test=Create("System.Console.WriteLine(\"Test\"); System.Console.ReadKey();");
        var helloWorld = Create("System.Console.WriteLine(\"Hello from Script!\"); System.Console.ReadKey();");

        test();
        helloWorld();
    }

    public static TestScript Create(string script)
    {
        // Feed it some code
        return ()=>_evaluator.Evaluate(script);
    }
}
```

`Mono.CSharp` is very flexible and has a lot of options [Mono C# REPL](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/tools+libraries/tools/repl/) is written based on this library. For more information about the library you can refer to Mono documents.

You can obtain `Mono.CSharp` package from Nuget `PM> Install-Package Mono.CSharp`